# Probability with 2 standard deviations of the mean

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Assume IQs of the population are normally distributed with mean 100 and standard deviation 15 and suppose  sample of 10 people. I am looking to find the probability everyone in the sample has an IQ within 2 standard deviations of the mean.[here my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0IEs.png) but it looks to complicated and I think probability should be around 95%

Comment: Well, what's the probability that a randomly selected individual is outside $2\sigma$ from the mean?

Comment: "*Find the probability that every datapoint in a normally distributed sample is within 2 standard deviations of the mean*" does not in any way depend on *which* normal distribution it was.  It doesn't depend on what the mean was or the standard deviation was.  It may as well have been the standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.  As for the probability?  This is found very clearly in tables in any science textbook or statistics book, or if you prefer can be calculated with calculator or calculus directly.

Comment: As to your actual question... yes... *around* $95\%$... see [68-95-99.7 rule on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%2068%E2%80%9395,99.73%25%20of%20the%20values%20lie)

Comment: I know this rule but how I can calculate?

Comment: $\int\limits_{-2}^2f(x)dx$ where $f(x)$ is the standard normal distribution's probability density function.  Or look at a chart like can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table)

Comment: Everyone in the comments is making this unnecessarily difficult for you. please see Ross Millikan's response below. His answer is correct and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that one person is within $2\sigma$ is about $95\%$ as you say.  The chance that all $10$ of the people are within $2\sigma$ is then about $0.95^{10}$, which is much smaller.